# Can I ask question like "How does Stack Exchange do this?"

Tags: discussion, scope

I just got pounded on Stack Overflow for a question asking "**How does Stack Exchange code X?**":

- [Send notification from server to client on server event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24354902/how-to-add-notifications-when-other-users-perform-activities)

I've seen it done before: [How does Stack Overflow generate its SEO-friendly URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-does-stack-overflow-generate-its-seo-friendly-urls), and be accepted by the community as a good and helpful question. Mine wasn't. Did I phrase it wrong (making it unclear), or is that kind of question not for Stack Overflow.

Comment: That question is too broad. We expect questions to be about actual programming problems. Your question would be on-topic if you showed the code that you have to implement a feature also used on the SE sites. You can get some highlevel stuff from [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/what-are-the-architecture-details-of-stack-overflow)

Comment: Okay, Got It. So I will show were I'm trying to perform the task, and ask how to do it.

Comment: You show the code you have and explain what doesn't work, as in input, processing, expected output.

Comment: @user3765372 the question you are using as reference is almost 6 years old.  The rules were quite different then.  If that same question was asked today, it would not fare nearly as well.

Comment: @psubsee2003:  I was thinking that a historical lock might be appropriate for that question, although it's written in a way that's both specific to Stack Exchange and generically helpful to others, so I'm conflicted...

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23594620/how-do-stack-overflow-desktop-notifications-work/) was asked recently and was well-received by the community. At the time, I flagged it for migration to Meta due to the way that it was asked (the specific phrasing of the question), but apparently it fits well enough within the scope of programming defined in the Help Center because of the answer I provided, so the flag was declined.

Comment: The scope of the site changes at times, so sometimes I see a new user asking "Why was my question closed? I found a bunch of others like mine that were not closed..." and then citing those examples. This often happens with recommendation questions, which *were* on-topic during the early days but were later made off-topic. Oftentimes what happens in that case is that a mod closes the cited questions, answers that the OP's question is off-topic, and also says "thanks for pointing out those questions, all of them have been closed accordingly".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Those Questions Are Too Broad

Both your question and the example question you gave are **Too Broad**, and should be closed according to [Stack Overflow's current guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions which are too broad, unclear, incomplete or primarily opinion-based may be [put on hold by the community](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) until they are improved.

### What Your Question Asks

Summarized below:

> #### [How to add notifications when other users perform activities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24354902/456814)
>
> So what is the correct way to do this, how does disqus and stack-exchange do this? I haven't written any code, since I don't even have a method...

### What Your Example Question Asks

Summarized below:

> #### [How does Stack Overflow generate its SEO-friendly URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25259/456814)
>
> What is a good complete [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) or some other process that would take the title:
>
> > How do you change a title to be part of the URL like Stack Overflow?
>
> and turn it into
>
> ```
> how-do-you-change-a-title-to-be-part-of-the-url-like-stack-overflow
> ```
>
> that is used in the SEO-friendly URLs on Stack Overflow?
>
> The development environment I am using is [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails), but if there are some other platform-specific solutions (.NET, PHP, [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29)), I would love to see those too.

### Questions About Stack Exchange

If you're interested about the implementation details of Stack Exchange sites, such questions would be on-topic here on Meta Stack Overflow if the question is specifically about Stack Overflow, or on-topic on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) if it's not specific to Stack Overflow, but would apply to Stack Exchange sites in general.

Note, however, that just because you ask about how something is implemented on a Stack Exchange site, the Stack Exchange team is not obligated to reveal to you all of their [Intellectual Property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_property) secrets, though they've actually given some answers about various technologies and algorithms that they use.

#### Examples

- [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network)
- [What are the architecture details of Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/what-are-the-architecture-details-of-stack-overflow)

Comment: Could I have rephrased my question to fit in the guidelines? If not, do you have any ideas of where to take it?

Comment: @user3765372 your question was closed as Too Broad and open-ended, so you need to make it less so. Please read [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask], and [ask]. If you just want to know about implementation details for comment notifications, you can ask that question here on Meta or on [meta.se], **but make sure that that question hasn't already been asked before first.**

Comment: I don't feel that the original question itself is too broad.  It asks a specific question, and likens it to how Stack Exchange does it.  It has a coherent and useful answer to it, which others can benefit from.    The question itself may not be all that stellar, but it's reasonable.  Instead of closing it, perhaps a historical lock on it may be better.

Comment: @Makoto you're referring to the [older question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25259/456814)?

Comment: That's right.  Only the original question.

Comment: // , It seems that helpless hand raisers are slowly getting weaned, especially if you look at how user3765372's questions have changed over time. An article about "helpless hand raisers" follows: http://www.educationworld.com/a_curr/columnists/jones/jones003.shtml