# How can this open-ended question be improved?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, scope

After multiple edits (rewrites), I still can't fix what I believe to be a [valid programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24354902/send-message-from-server-to-client):

> ### Send message from server to client
>
> My server has a piece of information that a client needs, but does not know it needs. That piece of information needs to get to the client in a very timely fashion (under 15 seconds). I also note that the client does not know that it wants this information.
>
> Furthermore I want to avoid extraneous client to server calls. The ideal method would be for the server to tell the client about this information. I was unable to find away to perform a server initiated data transfer.
>
> Ajax also didn't look promising because I would either have to perform lots of ajax requests to check if anything changed, or have one hanging Ajax request. Both of those are No-Nos.

**I would really appreciate help on improving this.**

Comment: Related question: [Can I ask question like “How does Stack Exchange do this?”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261296/456814). This user has been hard at work at trying to improve this question, so please consider offering some advice if you have any good ideas.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you were able to narrow it down enough to make a limited number of answers possible. I *thought* we had a pretty comprehensive canonical question about WebSockets and how to gracefully fall back to ajax when they aren't available, but I can't find it.

I re-opened the post (which was accumulating other re-open votes), someone should be able to nail a pretty good answer that talks about WebSockets, how to fall back on ajax polls if they don't work, and some of the better abstractions built around it to make it simpler. So far, one user has provided two possibilities that should be helpful to anyone wondering how to do this, so I'd say you're in fine shape.

Comment: Where you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028770/html5-websocket-vs-long-polling-vs-ajax-vs-webrtc or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet maybe?

Answer (score 5):

I did not get it. It looks like if a person has a bad question and nicely ask how to improve it on meta, people start to be nice, upvote it and reopen. I have nothing against being nice, but c'mon: this question is not only too broad, shows no prior research, it also was answered in significant depth [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028770/html5-websocket-vs-long-polling-vs-ajax-vs-webrtc?lq=1), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125507/how-can-i-send-and-receive-websocket-messages-on-the-server-side) times and has already a huge amount of duplicates.

I bet that person has not spent time trying to investigate the problem (otherwise he would find something like websockets or longpolling). So it is clearly a duplicate, too broad and in my opinion shows no research, but due to meta it has 8 upvotes.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson I tried to give my point that some questions are bad and can not be improved without investigating the topic and coming up with more concrete question.

Comment: I don't agree on the too broad.  Especially because the listed duplicates were also not closed as too broad.  But I do agree that it should have been closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @JasonMArcher there is a big difference: when http://stackoverflow.com/q/11077857/1090562 question was asked, a lot of technologies were new and it was hard to find normal explanation (it was 2 years ago). The guy1 is clearly asking: how do 1, 2 and 3 compare to each other. When guy2 is asking his question, half of the world already has an answer and is using these technologies for months. And his question is "how do I send something with php, but not using ajax".

Comment: @JasonMArcher Just to highlight: these questions are not listed as duplicates. His question is. You can not  say that a question asked 2 years ago is a duplicate of this guy's question which he posted 2 days ago.

Comment: I think you miss understood me.  I did not mean that the three questions were duplicates of each other, but that this question in the here and now should have been pointed to one (or more) of the 3 as a duplicate of those.

Comment: [Meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204311/165773)

Comment: @SalvadorDali I did do research, but only had a vague idea of what I was looking for. No matter what I typed I didn't find websockets or SSEs.... I don't know what I did wrong, but don't be to quick to point fingers. Hind-sight is clear sight. I wasn't lazy, if I was lazy I wouldn't have made as many edits and asked two questions here  on meta. I think your confusing laziness with poor research skills.... a weakness I'm willing to admit

Comment: // , @user3765372, participation in more open ended forums is an excellent complement to stackoverflow, and drastically improves your research skills. A lot of the reason people like stackoverflow is the same reason that people hate it: A lot of questions & answers get deleted. This just means we need more questions and answers to make up for that, improving the quality for all!